# Is it possible to run an ASP.NET 3.5 MVC 1.0 app on a server that supports ASP.NET 2.0 only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My host supports

- ASP
- ASP.NET v1.0/2.0
- ASP.NET Ajax
- Access Database Support
- MS Server Database Support (SQL Server)

I know by copying some of the files it's possible to run a .NET 3.5 [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application without .NET 3.5 installed on the client. Does the same hold for ASP.NET 3.5 MVC 1.0? Does MVC 1.0 support .NET 2.0?

My host is [Go Daddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy) in case it helps or matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mostly.** Scott Hanselman has an article describing [exactly how to do this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx). He notes:

> - This workaround is offered with exactly zero warranty or support. It's as-is, just an FYI on the blog. If this hack deletes files or kills your cat, you have been warned. No whining.
> - In practice, no one really knows what might break.  Microsoft didn't test this.
> - This just flat might not work for you. Sorry.

The trick:

> You can copy System.Core from your .NET 3.5 development machine (this is the machine running VS2008 that you're developing on) to the /bin folder on your .NET 2.0 SP1 machine. It's gotta be running .NET Framework 2.0 SP1 or this won't work. System.Core is probably somewhere around "C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089" on your machine, but you're a bad person for even asking.