# ASP.NET 4 running on server with ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Can I compile an ASP.NET 4 application, and run this on a server with ASP.NET 3.5 installed?

I have seen this method for ASP.NET 3.5 MVC running on servers with only 2.0 installed:
[Is it possible to run an ASP.NET 3.5 MVC 1.0 application on a server that supports ASP.NET 2.0 only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739393/is-it-possible-to-run-an-asp-net-3-5-mvc-1-0-app-on-a-server-that-supports-asp-ne)

Comment: Are you asking if 3.5 and 4.0 can run on the same machine, or if 4.0 will run with only 3.5 installed?

Comment: I'm asking if I can develop with 4.0, and host it on a machine with only 3.5 installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. The .NET 3.5 runtime is the same as the .NET 2.0. The .NET 4.0 runtime is new

Answer (score 0):

In VS you can set up any framework version number as the target - including 3.5

Comment: that doesn't mean you can use the language features from .net 4 in .net 3.5 however

Comment: That's right, but you can use nice new features of the development environment and still target the old runtime